# React dev strict mode on load animation using useEffect with empty dependency array triggered twice

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following code to load the last state from a connect 4 game and recreate it using a fancy animation:

```
useEffect(() => {
    const history = historyFromStateURL();

    (async () => {
        for (const colIndex of history) {
            await sleep(100);

            dispatch({
                type: 'CLICK',
                colIndex,
                isReplay: true,
            });
        }
    })();
}, []);
```

The problem is, that the code is not side effect free, if the effect is run twice, twice as many clicks will be dispatched and the state of the component will be different. Since I am using React strict mode, thats exactly what happens.

In my opinion the code should be fine, since the useEffect hook can only ever run once per component, but it seems react disagrees.

Any ideas how I could change the code to make it work in strict dev mode too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set a boolean flag to ignore the animation in the cleanup function for `useEffect`.

```js
let ignore = false;
(async () => {
    for (const colIndex of history) {
        await sleep(100);
        if (ignore) return;
        dispatch({
            type: 'CLICK',
            colIndex,
            isReplay: true,
        });
    }
})();
return () => ignore = true;
```